# Are there libraries that convert from Expression trees or CodeDOM to Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, codedom, reflection.emit

I found an interesting library that [converts expression trees to CodeDOM](http://linq2codedom.codeplex.com/). I am wondering if there are any libraries that convert from Expressions trees or CodeDOM objects to Reflection.Emit objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728224.aspx) may be what you're looking for?  It can emit an expression tree to a MethodBuilder.